# How to decide a std::vector Type in runtime depends on loop elements type?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, void-pointers, strategy-pattern

I have a list of my own data types, I want to convert it to std::vector of primitive type (int8_t/int/...).

I want to create a vector of primitive type (int32/int8) that will be choosen in runtime depends on my element type. (my list can not hold elements of different types)

I have this looop:

```
std::vector<void*> createPrimitiveList(MyClass list_data) {
    std::vector<void*> listPrimitive;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < list_data.Size(); ++index) {
        switch(list_data[index].type) {
            case MyClass::TYPES::INT32:
                listPrimitive.push_back(list_data[index].val);
            case MyClass::TYPES::UINT8:
                listPrimitive.push_back(list_data[index].val);
        }
    }

  
  return listPrimitive;
}
```

But I don't want to create vector of type void*, I want the actuall primitve type.
in case of the data is of type int8/char/... I don't want to use sizeof(void*) bytes)
I Tried to get type with 'using' keywork but using declaration requires a qualified

Can it be done in c++?

Comment: The type is always fixed at compile-time. Are you perhaps looking for `std::variant`?

Comment: possibly `std:any`?

Comment: I ma trying to test both (any/variant) with compiler 'x86-64 clang 13.0.1' with std=c++20 but getting:
error: no type named 'variant' in namespace 'std'

I found a "WA" to create vector<uint8_t> and use std::copy to fill it

will test if it will work

Comment: how did you end up with `list_data[index].val` being of different types in the first place? `operator[]` can only return one type

Comment: what is `MyClass` ? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Have you included the correct headers for variant and any?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat seems std::variant<vector<int>,vector<int8_t>> is the correct approach. thanks

Comment: `std::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<int8_t>>` implies every value is the same, but your example is examining every value for the type to cast it to. Which is right?

Comment: If all your elements must be of the same type, why is the element type stored in the elements and not in the list?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand everything correctly.

You are mentioning the strategy pattern in your tags. But I would guess that you should use a creational pattern, like factory or whatever.

But since you have already a type in your class `MyClass` like for example `MyClass::TYPES::INT32` you know already the return type of your function.

Additionally, there are many type trait functions available in the [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) library. You will nearly always find something that fits your needs.

Anyway. I would like to show you a function based on templates. That makes life more simple. Important is, that we can use a `type_trait` to detect the type of the underlying data of you class.

We use `std::tuple` as a type list. And some numeric selctor.

Then we can automatically get and select the needed type with [std::tuple_element_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element). This we will alias with a `using` statement. For example with

```
using Type = std::tuple_element_t<INT64, MyTypes>;
```

Then, a templated function will simply create the `std::vector` with the already known type. That is easy now.

And in main, we will use [Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to elegantly define `std::vector`s with the needed type and assign values using our function.

This could then look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

// Type list and selector
using MyTypes = std::tuple <int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t>;
constexpr int INT8{ 0 }, INT16{ 1 }, INT32{ 2 }, INT64{ 3 };

// Some demo classes
struct MyClassArray {
    using Type = std::tuple_element_t<INT8, MyTypes>;
    std::array<Type, 10> value{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
};
struct MyClassVector {
    using Type = std::tuple_element_t<INT16, MyTypes>;
    std::vector<Type> value{ 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 };
};
struct MyClassDeque {
    using Type = std::tuple_element_t<INT32, MyTypes>;
    std::deque<Type> value{ 31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,30 };
};
struct MyClassList {
    using Type = std::tuple_element_t<INT64, MyTypes>;
    std::list<Type> value{ 41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,40 };
};

// Create a vector with appropriate type
template <typename T>
auto createPrimitiveList(T& data) -> std::vector<typename T::Type> {
    return { data.value.begin(), data.value.end() };
}

int main() {
    // Define some classes
    MyClassArray mca{};
    MyClassVector mcv{};
    MyClassDeque mcd{};
    MyClassList mcl{};

    // Get vector with type dependent on input class 
    // Use Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD)
    std::vector i8 = createPrimitiveList(mca);
    std::vector i16 = createPrimitiveList(mcv);
    std::vector i32 = createPrimitiveList(mcd);
    std::vector i64 = createPrimitiveList(mcl);

    // Some debug output
    for (const auto i : i8) std::cout << (int)i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto i : i16) std::cout << (int)i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto i : i32) std::cout << (int)i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto i : i64) std::cout << (int)i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
}
```